# В чем разница выполнения префикса и постфикса

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем тут разница.

```
    class G1{
static int d=9; 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    G1 rt = new G1(); 
    G1 ew = new G1(); 
    
    System.out.println(rt.d ++);
    System.out.println(ew.d ++);
}
```

}
Выходные данные тут будут 9 и 10
А в следующем коде:

```
    class G1{
static int d=9; 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    G1 rt = new G1(); 
    G1 ew = new G1(); 
    
    System.out.println(rt.d +1);
    System.out.println(ew.d +1);
}
```

} будут 10 и 10

Comment: Коды то не одинаковые

Comment: Так это ж не одно и то же. Во втором случае статическая переменная `d` не модифицируется, а в первом дважды происходит ее инкремент (причем постфиксный, который возвращает значение до инкрмента)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rt.d++
```

равносильно

```
rt.d = rt.d + 1;
```

При этом постфиксный инкремент вначале возвращает значение, а потом прибавляет единицу к самому себе

в случае с

```
rt.d + 1
```

переменная `d` сама у себя ничего не увеличивает на 1. Происходит просто прибавление единицы и отдача его в параметр функции.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего стоит отменить что вы обращаетесь к полю `static` а это значит что оно уровня класса, а не объекта (инстаса). Другими словами когда вы обращаетесь как `rt.d` или `ew.d` то это одно и тоже поля класса в памяти и вообще правильно к нему обращаться по имени класса `G1.d`
Во-вторых как колеги уже заметили `d++` это `d = d + 1` Отсюда и инкримент (но помним постфиксный инкремент вначале возвращает значение, а потом прибавляет единицу в отличии от `++d`).

Comment: Про обращение по имени класса согласен, нужно было написать G1.d. Я правильно понял, что если написать ++d, то значения выведутся одинаковые, а точнее 10 и 10? Только не понятно как это записать System.out.println(rt.++d) ? Я еще только учусь)

Comment: @ИнститутITбизнеса  `++rt.d`